# Setting dates in the xAxis properly HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8gr4z6et/

I am trying to set the dates, of my data array, in the xAxis, as shown in multiple questions. However, this makes the series data invisible. If I remove the `new Date` it gives me an invalid date.

Any clue on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highcharts v2.2.4 it is required to use dates as timestamps in milliseconds. In newer versions it is allowed to use the format you have set: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xdrk9j78/

```
series: [{
    name: '',
    data: [
        [
            new Date("2019-07-15T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(),
            0
        ],
        [
            new Date("2019-07-16T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(),
            1
        ]
    ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/93obkhsd/